# Why do my React Native input fields constantly reset to their initial values?

Tags: react-native

I have a few screens in my React Native app where I want to receive some user input, but on these screens I also want to start with initial values in the fields when the user first comes to visit the screen, especially if they are updating existing data. I can't see how to do this, because the moment I provide a default value the inputs seem to cease to be editable. On `Picker` controls, they automatically reset themselves to the original value, on `TextInput` fields they reset themselves to default after a momentary blink.

In the event handlers I can see the changed value being received but that data is not passed back to the dropdown, even though the default values are configured to reference the same object that I am updating in the event handler.

This code reproduces the problem I am seeing:

```
import {Picker} from '@react-native-picker/picker';
// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {

  const scores = {
    positive: 1,
    negative: 2
  };

  const setScore = function(direction, scoreText) {
    console.log("Set "+direction+" to "+score+" currently: "+JSON.stringify(scores));
    let score = parseInt(scoreText);
    if ( direction == 'positive' ) {
      scores.positive = score;
    } else {
      scores.negative = score;
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        Select a different option in this dropdown and watch in astonishment as nothing happens!
      </Text>
      <Picker 
          onValueChange = { (itemValue, itemIdx) => setScore('positive', itemValue)} 
          selectedValue={scores.positive}
          >
            <Picker.Item key="1-0" label="0" value="0" />
            <Picker.Item key="1-1" label="1" value="1" />
            <Picker.Item key="1-2" label="2" value="2" />
            <Picker.Item key="1-3" label="3" value="3" />
            <Picker.Item key="1-4" label="4" value="4" />
       </Picker>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

This is visible in a working [Snack here.](https://snack.expo.io/R8n6Z0AbH)

I can't see this problem showing up elsewhere so it is probably a fundamental misunderstanding on my part about how the React Native Input system is supposed to operate. How can I use Input fields to receive input from my users while having a default value selected when the screen is first loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to track values mutable by user, as well as any dynamically changing values inside functional components. So instead of declaring scores as

```
const scores = {
  positive: 1,
  negative: 2
};
```

we can use useState hook

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
...
const [scores, setScores] = React.useState({
  positive: 1,
  negative: 2
})
```

You declare them with initial values, and it returns the current state and  setScores function that updates the state, so you can then set your state as

```
if ( direction == 'positive' ) {
  setScores({positive: score})
} else {
  setScores({negative: score})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are using a const to show value in React-Native (that is not the React way let me say). Why don't use a `useState` variable. Something like:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState({ positive: 1, negative: 2});
```

and then when you need to set them just call:

```
setValue({positive: score});
setValue({negative: score});
```

[Here](https://snack.expo.io/mf5a1plzi) your code modified.